# Priority Queue applications

Tags: c#

What are the computer applications of priority queue data structure ?I want to know about the computer processes or computer applications which make use of priority queues. I know one such application. We can use priority queue in the printer buffers. For example, suppose there are 3 priority levels. The user needs to specify his/her priority before giving the printing command. So the document in the buffer with highest priority will be printed first and so on.

So any other applications of this kind?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_Queue#Applications

Answer (score 2):

- [The A* algorithm for route finding.](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2010/04/a-algorithm.html)
- [Computing the "sliding median" or "moving median average" by maintaining queues of values in the window less than or equal to and greater than or equal to the current median, respectively.](http://ocamlnews.blogspot.com/2010/05/sliding-median.html)

Comment: It appears that the links are broken.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to give this in answer form to make sure that you see it. Some uses are detailed at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_Queue#Applications. This includes bandwith management and pathfinding algorithims.

Answer (score 0):

As an example of Priority Queue use, take a look at my series of posts about A* (A star) search. It contains source code implementation in C#.

In order to make the A* algorithm work we need to get the lowest-estimated-cost-path-discovered-so-far out of the list of paths under consideration. The standard data structure for doing so is the “Priority Queue”. Priority queues are so-called because they are typically used to store a list of jobs where each job has an associated priority.

Take a look at my blog posts to see the Priority Queue in action:

- [A* pathfinding search in C# - Part 1](http://www.leniel.net/2009/06/astar-pathfinding-search-in-csharp.html)
- [A* pathfinding search in C# - Part 2](http://www.leniel.net/2009/06/astar-pathfinding-search-csharp-part-2.html)
- [A* pathfinding search in C# - Part 3](http://www.leniel.net/2009/12/astar-pathfinding-search-csharp-part-3.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not advertising any resources, but I think the article [applications priority queue on geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/applications-priority-queue/) has done a great job of describing the most popular usages where PriorityQueue is very handy.

One more time, I'm just listing the applications they mentioned:

- Dijkstra’s Shortest Path Algorithm using the priority queue
- Prim’s algorithm
- Artificial Intelligence
- The priority queue (also known as the fringe) is used to keep track of unexplored routes, the one for which a lower bound on the total path length is smallest is given the highest priority.
- Heap Sort
- Operating systems
- Optimization problems
- Robotics
- Event-driven simulations
- Medical systems

Comment: [/help/referencing](/help/referencing) hint: your formatting is wrong. another hint: blockquotes.

Comment: nope. read my hints again.