# Applications of linked lists

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, linked-list

What are some good examples of an application of a linked list? I know that it's a good idea to implement queues and stacks as linked lists, but is there a practical and direct example of a linked list solving a problem that specifically takes advantage of fast insert time? Not just other data structures based on linked lists.

Hoping for answers similar to this question about priority queues: [Priority Queue applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306975/priority-queue-applications)

I have found one myself: A LRU (least recently used) cache implemented with a hash table and a linked list.

There's also the example of the `Exception` class having an `InnerExeption`

What else is there?

Comment: I think LRU uses a queue which is indirect application of linked lists in creating new data structures, but this definitely is better than "just applicable in other data structures"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work as a developer at a "large stock market" in the US. Part of what makes us operate at very fast speed is we don't do any heap allocation/de-allocation after initialization (before the start of the day on the market). This technique isn't unique to exchanges, it's also common in most real time systems.

First of all, for us, Linked lists are preferred to array based lists because they do not require heap allocation when the list grows or shrinks. We use linked lists in multiple applications on the exchange.

- One application is to pre-allocate all objects into pools (which are linked lists) during initialization; so whenever we need a new object we can just remove the head of the list.
- Another application is in order processing; every Order object implements a linked list entry interface (has a previous and next reference), so when we receive an order from a customer, we can remove an Order object from the pool and put it into a "to process" list. Since every Order object implements a Linked List entry, adding at any point in the list is as easy as populating a previous and next references.

Example off the top of my head:

```
Interface IMultiListEntry {

    public IMultiListEntry getPrev(MultiList list);
    public void setPrev(MultiList list, IMultiListEntry entry);

    public IMultiListEntry getNext(MultiList list);
    public void setNext(MultiList list, IMultiListEntry entry);

}

Class MultiListEntry implements IMultiListEntry {

    private MultiListEntry[] prev = new MultiListEntry[MultiList.MAX_LISTS];
    private MultiListEntry[] next = new MultiListEntry[MultiList.MAX_LISTS];

    public MultiListEntry getPrev(MultiList list) {
        return prev[list.number];
    }
    public void setPrev(MultiList list, IMultiListEntry entry) {
        prev[list.number] = entry;
    }

    public IMultiListEntry getNext(MultiList list) {
        return next[list.number];
    }
    public void setNext(MultiList list, IMultiListEntry entry) {
        next[list.number] = entry;
    }

}

Class MultiList {

    private static int MAX_LISTS = 3;
    private static int LISTS = 0;

    public final int number = LISTS++;

    private IMultiListEntry head = null;
    private IMultiListEntry tail = null;

    public IMultiListEntry getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public void add(IMultiListEntry entry) {
        if (head==null) {
            head = entry;
        } else {
            entry.setPrevious(this, tail);
            tail.setNext(this, entry);
        }
        tail = entry;
    }

    public IMultiListEntry getPrev(IMultiListEntry entry) {
        return entry.getPrev(this);
    }
    public IMultiListEntry getNext(IMultiListEntry entry) {
        return entry.getNext(this);
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is either extend MultiListEntry or implement IMultiListEntry and delegate the interface methods to an internal reference to a MultiListEntry object.

Comment: I suppose this only works if your linked list is intrusive? If so, it has downsides (list and items need to know of each other; an item can only be in as many lists as it has internal `next` pointers).

Comment: @delnan In the "pool" application it doesn't have to be intrusive since the pool is built before initialization, so you can take the generic approach where the pool entries are allocated by the list internally. But certainly in the "to process" application it's intrusive and you can run into some tricky problems if the Order can  exist in multiple lists.

Comment: @delnan It should be noted that you have to abandon _some_ of the principles of OO programming to gain performance.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the pool one, I glossed over that because I was already familiar with it. And yes, the most familiar, general, "good" design is often less efficient. I wasn't trying to question the value of these approaches in general. Though I wouldn't connect the principles that intrusive linked lists are in conflict with OO specifically - the benefits of non-intrusive lists apply just as much in a functional or procedural setting.

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be infinitely many and "good example" is a subjective term, so the answer to your question is highly debatable. Of course there are examples. You just have to think about the possible needs of fast insertion.

For example you have a task list and you have to solve all the tasks. When you go through the list, when a task is solved you realize that a new task has to be solved urgently so you insert the task after the task you just solved. It is not a queue, because the list might be needed in the future for reviewing, so you need to keep your list intact, no pop method is allowed in this case.

To give you another example: You have a set of names ordered in alphabetical order. Let's suppose that somehow you can determine quickly the object which has its next pointing to the object where a particular name is stored. If you want to quickly delete a name, you just go to the previous item of the object to be deleted. Deletion is also quicker than in the case of stacks or queues.

Finally, imagine a very big set of items which needs to be stored even after your insertion or deletion. In this case it is far more quicker to just search for the item to be deleted or the item before the position where your item should be inserted and then do your operation than copy your whole large set.

Answer (score 0):

hashmaps in java uses link list representation.
When more than one key hashes on the same place it results in collision and at that time keys are chained like link list.